# Contact form 7 Variable to recall later

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cookies, contact-form-7

I'm looking to recall a Contact Form 7 field input on a later page. Current flow is user fills out a cf7 form, form redirects to a signature plugin (ApproveMe) then to a payment page using WPSimple Pay. I have a function to add the total amount to the form automatically using an HTML variable.

My functions.php contains the following:

```
function simpay_custom_form_35_amount( $amount ) 
{

    $url_var = 'amount';
    $value = isset( $_GET[ $url_var ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ $url_var ] ) : $default;

    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'simpay_form_35_amount', 'simpay_custom_form_35_amount' );
```

this allows me to set the amount of form to charge: https://paymentpage/?amount=250

ISSUE/HELP WITH what I would like to do is if my URL contains ?amount=xxx to use the URL setting, but default to a contact form 7 value submitted earlier if the URL does not specify anything.

Comment: Well to start with you will have to define `$default` within the scope of the function. Maybe by passing it in as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

created a cookie using

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.wpcf7-submit', function(){
        if($('.total-cost .ctf7-total').length && $('.total-cost .ctf7-total').attr('data-number')){
            document.cookie = "sy_total_val="+$('.total-cost .ctf7-total').attr('data-number') + '; path=/';
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

total-cost was field from cf7 I wanted to pass.

then made default the cookie but override with URL variable if present

```
function simpay_custom_form_35_amount( $amount ) {

    $url_var = 'amount';
    if(!empty($_COOKIE["sy_total_val"])) $default = sanitize_text_field($_COOKIE["sy_total_val"]);

    $value = isset( $_GET[ $url_var ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ $url_var ] ) : $default;

    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'simpay_form_35_amount', 'simpay_custom_form_35_amount' );
```